# What is the difference between Material Design Lite and Angular Material Design?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I am building a application using Angular 2 as front end. I want my application to be designed with Material Design. I want to know the different between the 2 material designs mentioned below. Will I have any issues in future if I follow anyone of it. Is there any difference between them.

1. Material Design Lite - https://getmdl.io/
2. Angular Material Design - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Material Design Lite is a framework independent implementation with pure HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and can be used with or without any web framework.

Angular Material Design and Angular2 Material Design are Material Design implementation for Angular 1.x and Angular2. All components are Angular components (or directives) and they can't be used without Angular.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any advantage of using Angular2 Material Design over the independent implementation, like performance or features?

Comment: Sure, you can use it like other Angular components and directives by just adding them to providers and use them. With MDL you have to take care that you use them in a way that works with Angular2. Angular2 Material components are in very early state and only a few basic components are available. Custom themeing isn't supported at all yet as far as I know, while MDL is complete and stable.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do you think for a simple site Angular material is too much ? i mean if no angularjs is needed at all, just for the material look,what would you suggest ?angular material or MDL ?

Comment: MDL is probably the better option if Angular is not required. Angular introduces lots of complexity.

Comment: I was expecting that Angular would build their material components on top of Material Design Lite css but that was not the case. Now instead of using components to separate mainly behavior, state. They are using the components to also impose style structure instead of relying on css. They are direspecting one of the most successfull ideas of web to separate logic (javascript), content (html), presentation. If the philosophy that Angular is doing preaching worked, We would be still programming  Web Forms.

Comment: If you want to know how I think this should be done, take a look at VueJS implementation. They did exactly that. Created a uniform strucutured css style and on top developed some components on it. Style was enforced by css not by the reuse of components.

Comment: Using global styles doesn't work well with style encapdulation. You can use SASS to get a good part of both.